# Add label to Panel programmatically

Tags: c#, panel

So I have a form, and I want to add some Panels with some controls(labels, and radiobuttons) when the form loads.
And I want to do it from the code, of course(it's for making an application with tests, and the questions will be random)
This is what I have done till now:

```
List<Panel>ls=new List<Panel>();

private void VizualizareTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Panel pan = new Panel();
        pan.Name = "panel" + i;
        ls.Add(pan);
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Text = "l"+i;
        pan.Controls.Add(l);
        pan.Show();
    }

}
```

But it doesn't show anything on the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the panel just created to the Form.Controls collection

```
private void VizualizareTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Panel pan = new Panel();
        pan.Name = "panel" + i;
        ls.Add(pan);
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Text = "l"+i;
        pan.Location = new Point(10, i * 100);
        pan.Size = new Size(200, 90);  // just an example
        pan.Controls.Add(l);
        this.Controls.Add(pan);

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set also a position and a size for the panel

Comment: And check that you do not have a control such as an xtrascrollbar on the control. Then you need to call Controls.Add on the control you are showing. If it is e.g. sxtraScroll1 then you need to add the dynamic ones to that one.

Comment: The size and location tip applies also to your labels. (As you can see this could become very complicated in a short time)

Comment: Sorry, I mixed this issue with a DevExpress one. It xcould be any control. If you show  e.g. a PanelControl you need to add your dynamic ontrols on it. Otherwise it may not be shown. But since it already works, everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2dj1.png)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int X = 153;
        int Y = 34;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Panel pnl = new Panel();
            pnl.SuspendLayout();
            pnl.Location = new Point(X, Y);
            pnl.Name = "pnl"+i;
            pnl.Size = new Size(200, 57);
            pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Location = new Point(X - 100, Y - 17);
            lbl.Name = "lbl" + i;
            lbl.Size = new Size(75, 23);
            lbl.Text = "lable_" +i;

            pnl.Controls.Add(lbl);
            pnl.ResumeLayout(false);

            this.Controls.Add(pnl);

            Y = Y + 95;
        }
    }

why not display label2 & label3?
```