# My winform project has a panel, how do I draw button's and other toolbox items into the panel through code?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I know it isn't much, but this is all I got:

```
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Text = "sample text";
        textBox.Width = 200;
        textBox.Height = 50;
```

I have been programming c# for a while now, but Winforms are new to me. Google hasn't been of any help either.

Comment: Did you try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15385997/1726419

Comment: Question is really unclear. Are you literally asking for drawing over panel? or simply looking for `panel.Controls.Add(textBox);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Textbox to the control's collection of your panel instance.

```
panel.Controls.Add(textbox);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
YourPanel.Controls.Add(controlName);
```

And then: `YourPanel.Location = new Point(Coordinates for X, Coordinates for Y);` <- so you can move your control's position :P